# A-Frame AR.js app isn't recognizing my marker pattern, and also a black overlay upon loading the page

Tags: javascript, html, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

Here is the link: https://sixteendollars.github.io/

As you can see, upon clicking the link, there's a weird black overlay on the page.

In addition, upon pointing the camera at my marker image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vCPx.png), it's not recognizing the marker and popping up the A-Frame entity like expected. I'm not sure if this is a problem with the marker, the model, the way I'm accessing the assets pipeline, or what.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">

<a-scene embedded arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;">


    <a-marker type="pattern" url="assets/pattern-marker.patt">
        <a-entity             
        obj-model= "obj: url(assets/Batman.obj);
        mtl: url(assets/Batman.mtl)">></a-entity>
     </a-marker>
     <a-camera-static/>

</a-scene>

</body>

</html>
```

The directory structure:

```
assets
    pattern-marker.patt
    Batman.obj
    Batman.mtl
index.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I threw your code into this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGLBbG), and it's working properly. A couple of issues though.

**1) Always make sure how the scene behaves without ar.js**

The model is huge (you need to scale it down like a hundred times), and the 'mtl's are not working properly. You can see it in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/328buqk4/) fiddle.

You can either scale it down with blender / maya, or with the `scale` component:

```
<a-entity scale='0.1 0.1 0.1'></a-entity>
```

2) The 'overlay' is actually your model. `<a-marker-camera>` should be used as a point of view for the scene. If you want to place AR stuff on the marker, use `<a-marker>`:

```
 <a-marker type="pattern" url="assets/pattern-marker.patt">
    <a-entity all-my-models></a-entity>
 </a-marker>
 <a-camera-static/>
```

With the `<a-camera-static>` being the equivalent of a camera ([source](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/src/component-anchor.js#L226))

When the marker dissapears, the `<a-marker-camera>` makes sure, that the rendered models stay on the screen. So you see an initial position of the loaded model.

---

**Pics or didn't happen**
When you scale the model down, and put it inside a `<a-marker>`, you should see the models (the right one is without the `mtl`s)

[image]

### UPDATE

This is quite question specific, so i'm placing it separately.

1) MTL's. These console errors show, that you didn't upload some necessary files
[image]

2) Github pages. It takes a while to load on my laptop but its clearly there. Tried on firefox / chrome on windows.
[image]

Comment: Few questions: 1. Why does it work on CodePen but not with the GitHub Pages link? 2. I updated the HTML in the post what with you suggested. Am I doing it correctly there? 3. How do I scale down the models? 4. Is there anything I can do about the broken MTL?

Comment: @user10729497 i've added some input about scaling, and separately the other ones. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Ok so I added those missing files and scaled it down; the model still isn't really showing the texture (this is the model FYI https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/batman-b32c0e6881274e5e906626bbe14126d6). I'll just link you all the source code: https://github.com/SixteenDollars/BatmanAR

Comment: not sure about the mtl's, i've downloaded it as a gltf model and its working https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-56398818?path=index.html:19:34